# Steam OpenId and Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, openid, steam

I am having trouble using Steam as OpenId provider. Everything works fine until the callback to my site is made, I see the steam login web page and I can login with my user, but when the calback executes I get an exception.
I use play 2.2 and Scala. The code is very similar to the one found on the [play docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaOpenID)

```
  def loginPost = Action.async { implicit request =>
    OpenID.redirectURL("http://steamcommunity.com/openid",
      routes.Application.openIDCallback.absoluteURL(),
      realm = Option("http://mydomain.com/"))
      .map(url => Redirect(url))
      .recover { case error => Redirect(routes.Application.login) }
  }

  def openIDCallback = Action.async { implicit request =>
      OpenID.verifiedId.map(info => Ok(info.id + "\n" + info.attributes))
       .recover {
          case error =>
            println(error.getMessage()) //prints null
            Redirect(routes.Application.login)
        }
  }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Internal server error, for (GET) [/steam/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=error&openid.error=Invalid+claimed_id+or+identity] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[BAD_RESPONSE$: null]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:165) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
Caused by: play.api.libs.openid.Errors$BAD_RESPONSE$: null
    at play.api.libs.openid.Errors$BAD_RESPONSE$.<clinit>(OpenIDError.scala) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.openid.OpenIDClient.verifiedId(OpenID.scala:111) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.openid.OpenIDClient.verifiedId(OpenID.scala:92) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$openIDCallback$1.apply(Application.scala:29) ~[classes/:2.2.1]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$openIDCallback$1.apply(Application.scala:28) ~[classes/:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:357) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
```

I see in the returned URL this error message `openid.error=Invalid+claimed_id+or+identity` but couldnt find anything related.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Play Framework OpenID classes are not properly generating the redirect URL.  Print out the value of the `url` variable from this line in your code:

```
.map(url => Redirect(url))
```

It most likely looks something like this:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
 &openid.mode=checkid_setup
 &openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid
 &openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid
 &openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fsteam%2Flogin
 &openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com
```

This is incorrect per the OpenID 2.0 spec, specifically at http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#discovered_info:

> If the end user entered an OpenID Provider (OP) Identifier, there is no Claimed Identifier. For the purposes of making OpenID Authentication requests, the value "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select" MUST be used as both the Claimed Identifier and the OP-Local Identifier when an OP Identifier is entered.

Based on that, the generated redirect `url` variable **should** be:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
 &openid.mode=checkid_setup
 &openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
 &openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
 &openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fsteam%2Flogin
 &openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com
```

I've written up an issue for this on the Play Framework issue tracker:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3740

In the meantime as a temporary hack/fix, you can use any number of string replacement techniques on your `url` variable to set the `openid.claimed_id` and `openid.identity` parameters to the correct `http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select` value.